# How to change the request IP in HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I'm developing a website that will connect to a credit card processing gateway webservice. For security purposes this webservice accepts requests only from IP addresses that were previously informed to them.

Since I'm developing locally, my IP changes almost every day. Is there a way for me to change the IP address of a HttpWebRequest so that I can test the Webservice calls locally?

This webservice is accessed through a https address and the methods must be sent via POST.

Comment: Most payment gateways provide an open endpoint for testing purposes. Which gateway are you using?

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you managed to changes the source IP address of your requests, what you would be doing is called IP spoofing. The problem is that the source IP is used to route responses back to your machine, so since you somehow managed to change the IP address in the request packets, the response would never get back to you because that is not your IP address.

Comment: There are some environments where it's possible to spoof the IP address that's reported to the high-level application and keep the underlying IP addressed used by network layers as the true address.  This allows you to spoof the address and still get a response.  I don't know if ASP.NET has this vulnerability though, but I've tested it in ColdFusion and some Java servlet hosts in the past.

Comment: @Sam, I would be interested to hear more about this, specifically with TCP/IP traffic. Do you have any references/links?

Comment: here's a blog post I wrote up about it back in 2004.  I don't have any other references, just to say I've done it myself.  http://rewindlife.com/2004/04/20/remote_addr-and-remote_host-not-safe-for-use-in-security/

Comment: @Sam, so on the client side you where able to forge IP packets with a spoofed source address and then get reponses back to your machine? Just to confirm we are talking about the same thing, here is the wikipedia link to to what I am refering to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ip_spoofing

Comment: actually it was a lot simpler than that.  I sent an HTTP request to a server and include HTTP headers for remote address.  The web/app servers passed these headers along to the application instead of rewriting them with the true IP address.  Again, this was six years ago with ColdFusion, JRun, and iPlanet so I have no idea if it's possible to do the same thing today.  I just confirmed that it is **not possible to do it with ASP.NET/IIS** (or at least not as easily).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old post. But I was able to get this work for me, hope this will be useful for someone in need of similar issue

```
  ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
            {
                webRequest.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate(
                ServicePoint servicePoint,
                IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint,
                int retryCount)
                {
                    return new IPEndPoint(
                        IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"),
                        0);
                };
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out JSONP if your data is in the JSON encoding as that is exactly for the purpose of requesting data from a webserver other than the one sending the original webpage.