# Initiating web requests through secondary IP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

IP I have 1 NIC with a primary IP and a secondary IP configured on it, is it possible to launch a new WebBrowser in .Net and initiate the web requests through the secondary IP instead of the primary IP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebBrowser Control setting the out going ip address before navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407275/webbrowser-control-setting-the-out-going-ip-address-before-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

the OS, not a control, determines, basing on routing table, which route to use for connecting with target host, AFAIK

so if you want to communicate with host1 via if1 than if2, configure routing on OS level

Comment: do I have access to these settings via .Net?

Comment: @Mitchan: Not sure. Ask more general question here, on SO or on SF or try http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+routing+table

Comment: @Mitchan: You can probably make a manual WebRequest via preferred interface, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345387/how-to-change-originating-ip-in-httpwebrequest and related