# Specify IP End Point in FiddlerCore

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

I'm using FiddlerCore on a server with multiple network cards/IP's.  How can I specify which IP End Point FiddlerCore should use?

I'm looking for an interface similar to BindIPEndPointDelegate, as shown in [Sending HttpWebRequest through a specific network adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860893/sending-httpwebrequest-through-a-specific-network-adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging and found the setting, in Fiddler this is called the EgressIP.

General Documentation: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/egressip
In FiddlerCore you would set this preference using code something like this:

```
FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.network.egress.ip", "127.0.0.1");
```

You can read more about managing Fiddler Preferences here: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/prefs