# NIC binding for c# applications

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddler, nic

I need to be able to route all traffic from my application through a NIC of my choosing and be able to inspect and modify HTTP traffic. Currently, I can achieve my goals with a roundabout method due to a lack of time/resources:

client -> http proxy (fiddlercore) -> ssh client (putty/plink) -> ssh tunnel -> local ssh server

Using command line, I forcebindip putty/plink to desired NIC/interface and pass the ssh tunnel parameters (host, ports, dynamic, etc.). I then set the "X-OverrideGateway" flag to the putty/plink tunnel parameters.

This allows me to see/modify all HTTP traffic as well as specify which NIC to use but it's not elegant. Can I replace the ssh client/tunnel with a proxy of sorts using Socket.Bind()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860893/sending-httpwebrequest-through-a-specific-network-adapter