# how can able to specify which one of the 10 IPs with Tcp Akka?

Tags: tcp, ip, akka

Hi  I'm writing an application on a server that has assigned 10 IPs I use Akka TCP to fetch some data from the other server But when I make the connection I have been able to specify which one of the 10 IPs to make the connection from another server ???

Comment: like this in Akka Tcp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345387/how-to-change-originating-ip-in-httpwebrequest

Comment: no, anyone has an idea